# How to read from a text file I made in C

Tags: c, file, printf, readfile

I am new to C, I am just trying to read a simple text file I created in C. I made this file by clicking new -> empty file -> saving it to my desired location and then adding the file extension (.txt) the text file holds a sample sudoku board and the full file name is sudokuchar.txt.

The code I have to read from the file and print it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fpointer = fopen("sudokuchar.txt", "r");
    char input[100];
    while(fgets(input,100,fpointer))
    {
        printf("%s",input);
    }
    fclose(fpointer);
}
```

so when i compile the program does not print anything and returns -1. I assume something is wrong with the file i am trying to read from?? if some one could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: " my desired location" - unless that desired location is also the active working directory for your process when it runs, the posted code will fail to find the file and `fopen` will return NULL. Failing to check that, and rather mistakenly assuming it just worked, passing NULL as the file pointer to `fgets` then invokes *undefined behavior*. It would seem some error checking and runtime startup configuration changes are in order.

Comment: so how do i save the file to the active working directory?

Comment: Also note, `main ()` is a function of type `int` and should return either zero or a positive *8-bit* value to the shell on exit (e.g. `return 0;` if no error, `1-255` on error). Also note, the proper declarations for `main` are either `int main (void) {...` or `int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {...` (you will see the equivalent `char **argv` instead of `*argv[]`, and there are additional non-portable arguments accepted by some compilers). This isn't causing the read failure (a `fopen` failure is most likely), but getting the basics right helps.

Answer (score 1):

Always check the return values of `fopen` and other standard library calls. It's most likely that your file doesn't exist. You can make a nice user friendly error message using errno, just make sure to include errno.h. Overall, your code should work, but you NEED to check the return values of things, because `fopen` [returns NULL](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) if it can't find the file.

```
FILE *fpointer = fopen("sudokuchar.txt", "r");

if(fpointer == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: [Errno %d]: %s\n", 
            errno, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is advisable to check what file pointer returns. If file pointer returns 0 or NULL then File pointer is unable to point to the file name you had provided. Also you can use this

```
File *fp = fopen(file name with full path (i.e. /home/chex/read.txt),"r")
```

Check `man fopen`
FILE *fopen(const char *path, const char *mode);